# Is there any way to verify the chrome driver version during runtime in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to verify the chrome driver version compatibility during runtime. If the chrome driver version in local machine is compatible, then script continues execution on it, else it has to use the chrome driver given in project package.
Is there any way for it.

Answer (score -1):

use 2.28 of Chrome version which is stable.